# How to validate telephone field in billing information

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation

I want to apply validation with 10 digit mobile number on `telephone` field in billing information in magento checkout page.

For this I tried `pattern="\d{10}"` with `type="tel"` but it is not working.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you checked Regular expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="" title="Telephone" class="input-text  required-entry validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits" id="billing:telephone" placeholder="Mobile">
```

Comment: its working for an upper limit but lower limit still doesn't work means i can be procced even by entering 1 digit

Answer (score 1):

You can set pattern like below,

```
pattern="^\d{10}$" with type="tel"
```

Remove/clear cache  and check again.